# How to present a tableview and qrcode-scanner on same viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the bottom half of a screen to be an active qr-code scanner, and the other half of the screen to be a tableview. Whenever I scan a qr-code, it will check the tableview for a match and highlight it.

What would i need to use to make this happen?

I'm using the following cocoapod for the qr code (https://cocoapods.org/pods/QRCodeReader.swift).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks like that pod already has instructions for using your own view. So, start by getting that to work with a view on the bottom half of your controller.. Then, add a table view to the top half of the controller, and off you go.

Comment: 1. Create a tableview that is half the height of your `UIViewController` -- 2. Create a `QRView` provided your cocoapod, and put that at the half of your height on the bottom half of your `ViewController`. Tada...

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the input. I'm new to uiviews and i've tried reading the documentation but dont really understand how to implement it. Having a real hard time finding anything on this online. Is it the "Interface customization" you're refering to in the documentation? Thanks!

Comment: @Axxi - I just grabbed that [QRCodeReader](https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift) from GitHub, and the included Example app does exactly what you are asking -- it uses a view on the main screen to do the scanning. So, all you have to do is follow that example.

Comment: @DonMag I'm having a hard time implementing, mainly because i just cant find any friendly UIview tutorials online. Can i use the example with a uiview that i've setup through the storyboard or? Is there any example you can provide me so i can just see how it works? Thanks.

Comment: @Axxi - I don't want this to sound harsh, but if you're looking at that Example app and you don't understand how the view is being used, your question is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. Just search the web for `swift introduction to uiview` and start learning the basics.

Comment: @DonMag I understand and expected this answer. I do understand the very basics but the UIview part is very new to me and seems to be tricky. You mention that its easy to implement, therefore i suspect that i am missing a very simple part on how to integrate it, which is why a working example would help me to break it down and figure out what I was missing. But thanks for pointing out that they had an example, I do appreciate it. I'll try figuring out how to use it.

Comment: @DonMag Just found the example app, thought you were talking about the example code in the main github site, my bad. Thanks!